# windows service & updating c# console app

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, console-application

I have a windows service that executes a console app every hour and it's running with no problems. I didn't set this up though, and I'm not familiar with windows services at all.

Today I had to update the console app, so I presumed that if I just copied the exe file back into the folder were it was called from the windows service after I modified it it would be fine. But it looks like it stopped working.

I ran the console app mannually from the command prompt and it works fine though.

Any ideas on why this could have stopped working?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried stopping and re-starting the service?  When you start the service doe you get an error message? Or do you get an error message fullstop at any point now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first try to stop/start your service, then
try to uninstall and install your service again

you can do the first thing in administrative tools/services
install/uninstall with  installUtil